# Restore a bootloader with no accessible partitions?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, grub, opensuse, bootloader

I recently deleted my openSUSE partition, and before deletion was using the default SUSE bootloader whenever I wanted to access my other partitions, such as Win7. When SUSE went, so did the bootloader that my machine used for booting **everything**. Now I'm stuck with GRUB, and after some research on the internet it proved to be too difficult to boot partitions with it. I'm stuck with GRUB, and my laptop's recovery partition(which I got instead of a recovery disk, unfortunately) is inaccessible since I can't boot any partitions from GRUB. I don't want to have to buy a recovery disk. Is there any way to restore my bootloader to the Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have another computer, you can download the [Windows ISO](http://www.mydigitallife.info/windows-7-iso-x86-and-x64-official-direct-download-links-ultimate-professional-and-home-premium/) and burn it onto a DVD. You cab boot from that DVD and recover Windows 7 bootloader.

### Repairing

1.Boot from the DVD.
2.Select your language.
3.Select startup repair.

[image]