# Deleted bootloader when deleting Ubuntu partition, and I don't have a disk

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, partitioning, grub, bootloader

I deleted my Ubuntu partition to free up some hard drive space two days ago. I restarted my computer the next day and it doesn't boot up, just says

error: no such partition

Entering rescue mode

grub rescue> _

I don't have the Windows 8.1 disk and I know just the bootloader is deleted, Windows install is fine. I put Ubuntu 16.04 on a flash drive and tried to boot from that but it didn't work, just went to the same screen even after going to the BIOS to set the Lexar flash drive to default boot. Does anybody know a way to get the normal Windows bootloader?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/410108/537463 might be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but you may beable to reinstall the GRUB bootloader from the rescue prompt.

```
grub-install /dev/sdx
```

x = drive letter of course.

Comment: This is indeed not possible.